# SQL queries in batch don't execute

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, foxpro

My project is in Visual Foxpro and I use MS SQL server 2008. When I fire sql queries in batch, some of the queries don't execute. However, no error is thrown. I haven't used BEGIN TRAN and ROLLBACK yet. What should be done ??

Answer (score 0):

that all depends... You don't have any sample of your queries posted to give us an indication of possible failure.  However, one thing I've had good response with from VFP to SQL is to build into a string (I prefer using TEXT/ENDTEXT for readabilty), then send that entire value to SQL.  If there are any "parameter" based values that are from VFP locally, you can use "?" to indicate it will come from a variable to SQL. Then you can batch all in a single vs multiple individual queries...

```
vfpField = 28
vfpString = 'Smith'

text to lcSqlCmd noshow
   select 
         YT.blah, 
         YT.blah2
      into
         #tempSqlResult
      from 
         yourTable YT
      where 
         YT.SomeKey = ?vfpField

   select  
         ost.Xblah, 
         t.blah, 
         t.blah2
      from 
         OtherSQLTable ost
            join #tempSqlResult t
               on ost.Xblah = t.blahKey;

   drop table #tempSqlResult;
endtext 

nHandle = sqlconnect( "your connection string" )
nAns = sqlexec( nHandle, lcSqlCmd, "LocalVFPCursorName" )
```

No I don't have error trapping in here, just to show principle and readability.  I know the sample query could have easily been done via a join, but if you are working with some pre-aggregations and want to put them into temp work areas like Localized VFP cursors from a query to be used as your next step, this would work via #tempSqlResult as "#" indicates temporary table on SQL for whatever the current connection handle is.

If you want to return MULTIPLE RESULT SETs from a single SQL call, you can do that too, just add another query that doesn't have an "into #tmpSQLblah" context.  Then, all instances of those result cursors will be brought back down to VFP based on the "LocalVFPCursorName" prefix.  If you are returning 3 result sets, then VFP will have 3 cursors open called

```
LocalVFPCursorName
LocalVFPCursorName1
LocalVFPCursorName2
```

and will be based on the sequence of the queries in the SqlExec() call.  But if you can provide more on what you ARE trying to do and their samples, we can offer more specific help too.